# XRDP Server keyboard

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard-layout, remote-desktop, rdp, xrdp

I have a new Xubuntu 16.06 workstation that I have installed XRDP on and can connect via RDP however am having problems with the keyboard layout. The keyboard works fine from a console.

I have read many posts on this topic yest unable to resolve so far.

I understand the keyboard layouts are located in /etc/xrdp and as I am in Australia I need to use the "us" layout which is the default. km-0409.ini

I connect to my workstation using Remmina the keyboard works differently than when I connect using Windows RDP and differently again to when I connect using a thin client.

When in an active XRDP session how can I determine which keyboard layout is being used and can I set one layout to be used as the default regardless of client?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange problem you have.... By default, the xrdp session would be using the en-US keyboard layout....If en-us is the only keyboard layout you are using, you should have no keyboard issue whatever remote client you are using.

To configure a keyboard layout for xrdp, you can execute the following commands **(run this command on the Console not in the xrdp console)**

> **Step 1** : You go to the /etc/xrdp directory
>
> **Step 2** : you issue the command setxkbmap -layout <%your layout%> to define which keyboard map/layout to use
>
> **Step 3** : create a copy of the km-0409.ini file into the same directory.
>
> **Step 4** : Check that you have a backup of your file by typing the dir or ls command
>
> **Step 5** : update the file by issuing the following command sudo xrdp-genkeymap km-0409.ini

Now, to check which keyboard layout you have when connected to xrdp, if you are using the **latest xrdp package**, you can either user the GUI or the following command line

setxkbmap -query

if you are using an older version of the xrdp package, you will probably receive an error message... (something like extension not availale...)

Check the following link for step by step instruction of xrdp and xubuntu 16.10, this might solve your issue... (check this [link](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=10355))

Hope this help
Till next time
See ya