# XRDP not set keyboardmap on Ubuntu 16.04.6

Tags: 16.04, keyboard-layout, xrdp

I'm trying to use keyboard layout pt-br abnt2 through xrdp, without success.

I'm using a newly created virtual machine with Ubuntu 16.04.6 (I have to use this specific major version).

I installed xrdp via apt-get install.

Via terminal or main window I'm able to use the keyboard layout correctly.

**Via xrdp the keyboard only works as US.**

I follow the procedure to create the specific pt-br abnt2 (km-0416.ini) file inside /etc/xrdp, restart the xrdp, without success, as presented in [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412755/xrdp-how-to-change-keyboard-layout)  [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831358/xrdp-server-keyboard)

I already tried change the window manager to lxde, lubunty, xfce4, without success in getting the right key-map.

All the times I restart the VM, restart the service.

I tried even remove all the km-xxxx.ini files from /etc/xrdp, without success. Noting works this way.

I keep only km-0416.ini. This way when I try to connect remotely the xrdp does not works.

I keep the km-0409.ini and km-0416.ini. This way the remote connection to xrdp works, but only in US mode.

I tried use a km-0416.ini created in the main terminal of the VM, I tried some download versions from internet, without success in getting my keyboard map. Always in US keymap.

I don't know what can I do anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue.

I execute the procedure as in [site](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=10355),

```
# Set keyboard layout in xrdp sessions 
cd /etc/xrdp 
test=$(setxkbmap -query | awk -F":" '/layout/ {print $2}') 
echo "your current keyboard layout is.." $test
setxkbmap -layout $test 
sudo cp /etc/xrdp/km-0409.ini /etc/xrdp/km-0409.ini.bak 
sudo xrdp-genkeymap km-0409.ini
```

but before generating the layout I stop xrdp, and generate the new km-xxxx file.

I also override the km-0409.ini, even thought the br code being 0416.

**I don't known if this is a bug or if override the 0409 as I did is the correct way of setting the keymap for xrdp.**

Also is worth to mention that although the 'ç' key start to work and other special keys, the created keymap does not match the key "/?" (not work at all) in abnt2 keyboard, arrows(not work) and Insert/Home keys respond with '/' and '?'.

In order to solve this issue I had to test other km-0409.ini files. With the file from [amartinstechnet](http://amartinstechnet.blogspot.com/2016/09/configurar-teclado-lxde-abnt2-x11rdp.html) I was able to use all keys from anbt2 keyboard correctly.

Maybe the file from a newer Ubuntu version work correctly.

Now the xrdp keyboard is responding to Brazilian special keys correctly.